# Move files from one symlink directory to another symlink directory

Tags: linux, shell-script, mv, ln

I want to move files in a symlink directory to another symlink directory, e.g. suppose that I do have symlink `a` and `b` directories in the same level and `a` contains `file.txt`

```
a/
 |--- file.txt    
b/
```

When I use the following command to move `file.txt` from `a` to `b` which is in one-level up:

```
cd a/
mv file.txt ../b/
```

I got the error that no such directory because `a` and `b` do not share the same top-level directory.

Any ideas to solve this problem or previous thread that already discussed this that I might have overlooked?

Comment: I just created two symbolic links that point to directories and was able to do that. You may want to add a bit more detail to the question, such as where those symlinks point to.

Comment: cd to the directory above a and b and `mv a/file.txt b/`

Comment: I don't think that your "_suppose that I do have symlink a and b directories in the same level_" means what you think it does. You don't symlink directories together: one is still the real directory and the other simply points to the first. This is unlike hardlinks between files, where both files end up being the same. // Please show in your question the output of `ls -ld a b` for appropriate values of `a` and `b` shown in your example